# Killing a daemon process through cron job/runnit

Tags: python-2.7, cron

I have a python file which starts 2 threads - 1 is daemon process 2 is to do other stuff. Now what I want is to check if my 2 thread is stopped then 1 one also should stop. I was suggested to do so by cron job/runnit.. I am completely new to these so can you please help me achieve the goal

Thanks

Comment: It could potentially create a race condition where the cron job will kill 1 while it starts up because 2 is down. Why not modify 2 to kill 1 on exit?

Comment: @alvits - can you please brief me on this...

Comment: In your python script, after creating the 2 threads, wait for thread 2 to complete. In threads this is called joining the thread. After joining thread 2, you can then kill thread 1. This is not necessary though if thread 2 is running a script. If thread 2 is running a script, you can kill the daemon at the end of the script.

Comment: So if i put t1.kill in finally block of my t2 then will it get actually killed?

Comment: No you can't, python won't let you. Here's how you can work around it https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/python-cookbook-2nd/0596007973/ch09s03.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way out is to create this daemon as a child thread so it automatically gets killed when parent process is killed